# Why printf inside if condition works in c?

Tags: c, if-statement, printf

```
if(printf("Hello world")){}
```

The output for above code is

```
Hello world
```

My friend told me that the function printf returns the length of characters which is non zero here, so the condition is true.

But I can't understand why it executes that printf statement. Shouldn't printf be executed only when it is inside `{ }`?

Comment: How could `printf` return any value if it is not executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *expression* within `if(`*expression*`)` is *always* evaluated, and in your case that's a call to `printf`.

The value of this expression is used to determine if the body (blank in your case) of the `if` is run.

Answer (score 0):

**printf()** function return the number of characters that are printed. If there is some error while printing, it will return a negative value.
Look at this snippet from GNU C library.

```
    int
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  int done;
  va_start (arg, format);
  done = __vfprintf_internal (stdout, format, arg, 0);
  va_end (arg);
  return done;
}
```

Here **printf returns 11** since, the count of characters it printed is 11.

if(11) is true => It will be true as 11 is a positive integer, so the body of if() will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate the return value from `printf()` function, the program **must execute it.**  This is why the printing happens.  It is executed just to evaluate the return value.  This is often called *side effect* or *collateral effect.*  C allows any expression in the test part of  an `if` statement except one that returns `void` (another way of saying *no return function* or procedure), union or struct

Comment: Re “C allows any expression in the test part of an `if` statement except one that returns `void`”: Per C 2018 6.8.4.1 1, it allows expressions with scalar type, so the type shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer, not `void`, structure, or union type. (Also not array or function type, but those would be converted to pointers and so are not relevant.) Also, an expression does not “return” a value. Functions return values. Expressions evaluate to values or produce values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thanks for your corrections about my bad english, but IMHO, this is a channel of C, and I see no difference in the meaning of sentences _any expression... except one that returns `void`_ against _... one that evaluates to `void`_  Anyway, I have to admit my english is too bad, but please, as I'm 59 now, I don't feel well at school again.  I feel you'll appreciate my comment.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not a matter of English or of natural language. The constraint for `if` in the C standard says that the `x` in `if (x) …` shall not be a structure type or a union type, as well as that it shall not be void. As for functions, if `f` designates a function, you can use `if (f) …`, because it will be automatically converted to a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

printf is returning 11 , cause the count is 11.